# translate C unsigned long long and bitwise in for loop to c#

Tags: c#, c

Having

```
int i, k;
unsigned long long x, y;
k = 5;
for (x = 0; x < 1ULL<<(2*k); ++x) {
    for (i = 0, y = x; i < k; ++i, y >>= 2)
        putchar("ACGT"[y&3]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

How can I translate `for (x = 0; x < 1ULL<<(2*k); ++x)` unsigned long long 1ULL and bitwise to c#?

I was trying

```
    public static ulong aux(int val){
        ulong result = ????? << val;
        return result;
    }
    public static void main() {
        int i;
        int k =5;  
        ulong  x,y;
        for (x = 0; x < aux(2*k) ; ++x) {
            for (i = 0, y = x; i < k; ++i, y >>= 2){
                Console.Write("ACGT"[y&3]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

How to translate that parts of code `x < 1ULL<<(2*k);` and `"ACGT"[y&3]`?

Comment: What range do you have for `k`?

Comment: Are writing obfuscated code manually?

Comment: @HenkHolterman well I am thinking on following your advice and on case k>=32 do other function and do recursion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not have `long long` and it would be hard to replace. As long as `k = 5` however it is not too relevant, a simple `ulong` should do:

```
ulong result = 1UL << val;
```

Your troubles will start when `(2*k) >= 64`

And the output needs a cast to int :

```
 Console.Write("ACGT"[(int)(y & 3)]);
```

Comment: What about `putchar("ACGT"[y&3]);` code line, What would be the best way to translate it?

Comment: I think that would become `Console.Write("ACGT"[(int)(y & 3)]);`

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to work out what the C code is actually doing, rather than trying to translate directly. The term `1ULL<<(2*k)` just means "take value 1 and shift it ten bits to the left". In other words 2^0 becomes 2^10, which is 1024. So replace `x < 1ULL<<(2*k)` with `x < 1024`.

Likewise `"ACGT"[y&3]` just means "obtain the character at position y bitwise-anded with 3 from the string "ACGT". So assign "ACGT" to a named constant and use the same technique to obtain the character at that index.

Comment: Until `k` changes. Even the `2*` may make sense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman k doesn't change. It's 5. I don't follow your comment therefore.

Answer (score 2):

Both lines can be expressed very similarly in C#.  The C line:

```
 for (x = 0; x < 1ULL<<(2*k); ++x) {
```

Translates in C# to

```
 for (x = 0; x < 1UL<<(2*k); ++x) {
```

(Note the suffix 1UL (unsigned long) instead of 1ULL (unsigned long long).

The C line

```
putchar("ACGT"[y&3]);
```

Requires a cast in C# and translates to

```
Console.Write("ACGT"[(int)y & 3]);
```

The cast is required because the indexer, [`String.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), can only accept a signed integer as an argument.